# Implementing a Min Heap in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, heap

I'm having trouble with one of my test cases and I can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated. I tried implementing a min-heap with number types but something seems to be off. I tried to make the class as clear as possible. The expected order for a min-heap should be in ascending order when removing elements, for example: 1,2,3,4,5,6.

Min Heap Class:

```
class MinHeap {
  
  constructor() {
    this.heap = [];
  }
  
  getLeftChildIndex(parentIndex) { return 2 * parentIndex + 1; }
  getRightChildIndex(parentIndex) { return 2 * parentIndex + 2; }
  getParentIndex(childIndex) { return Math.floor((childIndex - 1) / 2); }
    
  hasLeftChild(index) { return this.getLeftChildIndex(index) < this.heap.length; }
  hasRightChild(index) { return this.getRightChildIndex(index) < this.heap.length; }
  hasParent(index) { return this.getParentIndex(index) > 0 };
    
  leftChild(index) { return this.heap[this.getLeftChildIndex(index)]; }
  rightChild(index) { return this.heap[this.getRightChildIndex(index)]; }
  parent(index) { return this.heap[this.getParentIndex(index)]; }

  heapifyUp() {
    var index = this.heap.length - 1;
    while(this.hasParent(index) && this.parent(index) > this.heap[index]) {
      this.swap(this.getParentIndex(index), index);
      index = this.getParentIndex(index); 
    }
  }
    
  heapifyDown() {
    var index  = 0;
    while(this.hasLeftChild(index)) {
      var smallerChildIndex = this.getLeftChildIndex(index);
      if(this.hasRightChild(index) && this.rightChild(index) < this.leftChild(index)) {
        smallerChildIndex = this.getRightChildIndex(index);
      }
        
      if(this.heap[index] < this.heap[smallerChildIndex]) {
        // No need to continue, we are in order
        break;
      } 
        
      this.swap(index, smallerChildIndex);
      index = smallerChildIndex;
        
    }
  }
      
  swap(index1, index2) {
    var temp = this.heap[index1];
    this.heap[index1] = this.heap[index2];
    this.heap[index2] = temp;
  }
    
  peek() {
    if(this.heap.length === 0) throw Error("Error: Heap underflow");
    return this.heap[0];
  }
    
  getSize() {
    return this.heap.length;
  }
    
  isEmpty() {
    return this.heap.length === 0;
  }
    
  remove() {
    if(this.heap.length === 0) throw Error("Error: Heap underflow");
    var item = this.heap[0];
    this.heap[0] = this.heap[this.heap.length - 1];
    this.heap.pop();
    this.heapifyDown();
    return item;
  }
    
  add(item) {
    this.heap.push(item);
    this.heapifyUp();
  }
}
```

Test Case Fail:

```
var heap = new MinHeap();
var list = [];
heap.add(1);
heap.add(1);
heap.add(2);
list.push(heap.remove());
heap.add(4);
list.push(heap.remove());
heap.add(3);
list.push(heap.remove());
heap.add(6);
list.push(heap.remove());
heap.add(3);
list.push(heap.remove());
heap.add(4);
list.push(heap.remove());
heap.add(5);
list.push(heap.remove());
list.push(heap.remove());
list.push(heap.remove());
console.log(list); // logs [1,1,2,3,4,3,4,5,6]
```

Something is wrong with my logic but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: "Something" is off? Perhaps describing what happens v. what you expect would be helpful.

Comment: it's pretty clear from the output in the test case [1,1,2,3,4,3,4,5,6] that it's not in order...

Comment: @milanf It would help however if you could explicitly state what the expected order is. Can you please [edit] the question to add this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the line

> ```
> hasParent(index) { return this.getParentIndex(index) > 0 };
> ```

which should be

```
hasParent(index) { return this.getParentIndex(index) >= 0 };
```

or

```
hasParent(index) { return index > 0 };
```

With the broken implementation, adding `3` to the heap `[4, 6]` does not propagate it up properly, because index `2` is not considered to have a parent.

Answer (score 0):

Bergi pointed our that, in this particular implementation, `hasParent()` could be simplified to an expression that's so minimal it's probably better to inline it.

For developers arriving at this question looking for a good way to program a min heap in JavaScript, I've worked on making an implementation that's as clear as possible:

```js
class MinHeap {
  constructor() {
    this.data = [];
  }

  peak() {
    return this.data[0];
  }

  push(value) {
    this.data.push(value);

    let i = this.data.length - 1;
    while (i > 0) {
      const parentIndex = Math.ceil((i / 2) - 1);
      if (this.data[i] < this.data[parentIndex]) {
        this.swap(i, parentIndex);
        i = parentIndex;
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  pop() {
    // 1 or no remaining items is a special case
    if (this.data.length < 2) {
      return this.data.pop();
    }

    const min = this.data[0];
    this.data[0] = this.data.pop();

    let i = 0;
    while (true) {
      const [leftIndex, rightIndex] = [(i * 2) + 1, (i * 2) + 2];
      const leftValue = this.data[leftIndex] ?? Infinity;
      const rightValue = this.data[rightIndex] ?? Infinity;

      // If both children are larger than the candidate, we're done.
      if (leftValue > this.data[i] && rightValue > this.data[i]) {
        break;
      }

      // Otherwise pick the index of the smallest value
      const smallestIndex = leftValue < rightValue ? leftIndex : rightIndex;

      this.swap(i, smallestIndex);
      i = smallestIndex;
    }

    return min;
  };

  swap(i1, i2) {
    const val1 = this.data[i1];
    this.data[i1] = this.data[i2];
    this.data[i2] = val1;
  }
}
```

Usage and behavior:

```js
const heap = new MinHeap();
heap.push(2);
heap.push(1);
heap.push(3);

heap.pop(); // 1
heap.pop(); // 2
heap.pop(); // 3
```

Suggestions for improvements is welcome! There is also a [full explanation of the approach](https://mitchlloyd.com/javascript-heap) for people that aren't familiar with the array-backed-tree and "sink" and "float" heap algorithms.